# Trigger update on another table after insert

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the field current_price in table stock to be updated when we insert new into table stock_changes.

So stock.current_price should be updated to stock_changes.current_price

I have tried with triggers but it wont work.

```
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock
AFTER INSERT ON stock_changes
FOR EACH ROW
  UPDATE stock
     SET current_price =NEW.current_price
   WHERE id = NEW.stock_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `DELIMITER`.

Try this :

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER update_stock
AFTER INSERT ON stock_changes
FOR EACH ROW
begin
  UPDATE stock
     SET current_price =NEW.current_price
   WHERE id = NEW.stock_id; 
end;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: With this code i get the error: `#1235 - This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'multiple triggers with the same action time and event for one table` @Hamed Kamrava

Comment: This error means you already have an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `stock_changes` table. Drop it first...